# How to fix this strange padding in bootstrap form?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
            <label>From:</label>
            <input type="text" class="input-sm form-inline" name="start" />
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
            <label>To:</label>
            <input type="text" class="input-sm form-inline" name="end" />
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

when I change class="form-control" for input, it will be ok, but it also change size of whole form :(

Answer (score 0):

Solve:

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-daterange" id="datepicker">
            <span>From:</span>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="input-sm form-inline" name="start"/>
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-daterange" id="datepicker">
            <span>To:</span>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="input-sm form-inline" name="end"/>
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```